# Animating a Slider with DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

What I try to do should be fairly simple, but for whatever reason it doesn't work.
The expected behavior should be that the slider thumb goes from `0 => 100` (silder min=0 max=100) which means from left to right, then back again, again to the right and waiting there for 5 seconds and thats it, like KITT (knight rider).

So far the only thing I achieved is that it starts goes to the right and thats it, stops there and doesn't do anything, no further animations:

```
storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_OnCompleted;

var doubleKeyFrame = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0))));                       
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(100, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5))));
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5))));
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(100, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3))));
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(100, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5))));

Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleKeyFrame, slider);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleKeyFrame, new PropertyPath("Value"));
storyboard.Children.Add(doubleKeyFrame);

storyboard.Begin(slider);
```

I'm playing with that now since hours and I have no idea. Please maybe somebody could help me out here a bit.

King regards, Bernhard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I added `RepeatBehavior.Forever` and Duration for `doubleKeyFrame`:

```
var storyboard = new Storyboard();

var doubleKeyFrame = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(100, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0))));
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5))));

doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0))));
doubleKeyFrame.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame(100, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3))));

doubleKeyFrame.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
doubleKeyFrame.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleKeyFrame, slider);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleKeyFrame, new PropertyPath("Value"));
storyboard.Children.Add(doubleKeyFrame);

storyboard.Begin(slider);
```

Comment: thanks a lot first of all, first time I see it moving left and right, but I still don't understand how and why your solution is working. Also I would have done the keyframes differently. How would I do that if I would like to pause on each side a bit/some seocnds, maybe you could give me some ideas.